# atk6-flood_router26 wlan0 makes network crash

Tags: networking, 15.04, crash

I was watching a video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfsfNWHCKK0) on a network attack. Wanting to try this on my own network with my `Ubuntu 15.04` laptop and a Windows 10 virtual machine, I just did a `sudo apt-get install thc-ipv6` and then a `sudo atk-flood_router26 wlan0`, and well this made my internet connection to stop. I had to reconnect to my wireless network again, in order for the internet to work, this shouldn't be happening should it?

Comment: What shouldn't be happening? The connection being cut-off or the connection coming back after reconnection?

Comment: I taught my  linux machine was supposed to stay online while the attack is on and at least  not have  to manually reconnect after the attack is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flood_router26 will crash the whole network in my experience, it'll even affect my Linux machines.

Answer (score 3):

When you use flood_router26, this is exactly what is supposed to happen, crash a network. What were you exactly wanted to do?

Comment: Yup, was wrong sorry for the comment.